# MySql query: all value with same name in a single row

Tags: mysql

I have this table, where *value* are *varchar*:

```
| id  |   name   |  value  |
|  1  |  mario   |   321   |
|  2  |  pizza   |   455   |
|  3  |  mario   |   761   |
|  4  |  pizza   |   112   |
|  5  |  hobby   |   142   |
```

I would like to extract all value in a single column like the following:

```
|   name   |    values   |
|  mario   |   321, 761  |
|  pizza   |   455, 112  |
|  hobby   |     142     |
```

I new that I have to use `concat ', '` but I can't understand how to group the name with all his value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` clause with [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(value) AS values
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: He needs space with seperator

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY clause with seperator like **', '**

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR ', ') AS values
FROM [Put Table Name Here]
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  name, GROUP_CONCAT(value) as value FROM table_name  group by name
```